# Unix shell script - purpose of colon

Tags: shell, unix

I have come across a shell script with a line which reads as follows

```
Pfile=/params/tech1.dat:$Pfile;export Pfile
```

The purpose is to create and export a variable called `Pfile` containing value `"/params/tech1.dat"`

But what is the `:$Pfile`` doing ?   Specifically what purpose is the colon serving ?

Have trawled lots of Unix info sources and manuals but cannot find an example which helps explain the above.

Comment: The `:` means nothing in the given context - it's just part of the text. However, `$PFile;` is replaced with the current value of the PFile variable. To see what `:` means in the relevant context, find out where PFile is used (and how). It may be useful to inspect PFile before and after said assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The colon serves as a delimiter on many variables that list paths. It is just a character that is chosen by convention for that purpose.

Here, the piece of code assigns to `Pfile` the string that is obtained by evaluating the right hand site, which consists in a constant string `/params/tech1.dat:` and a variable `$Pfile`. It would perhaps appear more clearly if it were written `Pfile="/params/tech1.dat:$Pfile";export Pfile`.

In your specific example, `/params/tech1.dat` is prepended to `$Pfile` so that, assuming the value of `$Pfile` is `/other/path` it then becomes `/params/tech1.dat:/other/path`. This is understood by many programs as meaning: look in `/params/tech1.dat` then in `other/path`.

Common examples: `PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, LIBRARY_PATH, CPATH, PYTHONPATH`, etc.

If `$Pfile` is previously unset or empty, it ends up with a trailing colon: `/params/tech1.dat:` which may, or may not, depending on your program, be understood as the working directory (it is the case for the above-listed examples).

Note that `:` is a valid character in a path name in many file systems so in the unlikely event that some path contains one, it should probably be escaped.

Finally, note that in other contexts, `:` is a Bash function that does nothing.

Comment: The most common example being [`PATH`](http://kb.iu.edu/data/acar.html). Might be worth explaining that this scriptlet isn't _creating_ the `Pfile` variable it is _prepending_ to it.

Comment: Actually assignments do not do word splitting on the assigned value. So quoting is not necessary even if $Pfile contains whitespace initially.

Answer (score 2):

That prepends the path `/params/tech1.dat` to whatever `Pfile` might already have in it. So `Pfile` might already be:

```
echo $Pfile
/foo/bar:/blah/bleh
```

Then you do execute the statement:

```
Pfile=/params/tech1.dat:$Pfile;export Pfile
```

and you get:

```
echo $Pfile
/params/tech1.dat:/foo/bar:/blah/bleh
```

As was mentioned by others, the colon (`:`) is typically used as a path or field delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you are appending the existing value of `$Pfile` to `/params/tech1.dat`.  If there is no existing value, you will get `/params/tech1.dat:` as the value assigned to `$Pfile`.  `:` acts as a delimiter between the two values.

Typically, `:` is used as a delimiter for directories in shell variables such as `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.  Don't know if you have a certain reason to use `:` in your variable.

Comment: Strictly speaking you would get `/params/tech1.dat:`